# DateTime of packet from Seconds and Microseconds

Tags: c#, datetime, packet

I have class that open `Pcap file`and have this 2 members: `Seconds` and `Microseconds` (both int).
How can i create from this 2 fields `DateTime` ?

This is what i have try:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, packet.Seconds);
```

And got this error:

> Hour, Minute, and Second parameters describe an un-representable
>   DateTime.

Comment: what values are you getting in packet.Seconds? are you sure that's not a relative time?

Comment: It sounds like you really need a `TimeSpan` for this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the seconds parameter in that constructor must be between 0 and 59 inclusively. What you really want is 1970-1-1 plus the number of seconds.

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(packet.Seconds).AddSeconds(packet.Microseconds / 1000000.0);
```

Comment: And what about my Microseconds  ?

Comment: Well microseconds are just a fraction of a second. You can use the same AddSeconds method to add microseconds, you just need to convert the microseconds to seconds. From googling, there are 1,000,000 microseconds in a second. So ````dateTime.AddSeconds(packet.Microseconds / 1000000.0);```` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(packet.Seconds).AddTicks(packet.Microseconds * 10);
```